# Close only target object

Tags: jquery

I use this quick snippet with an image to close a `show`/`hide` `DIV`:

```
  $('a.close').click(function() { 
     $('#timeline-2010-1').hide(); 
     $('#timeline-2010-2').hide();

     return false; 
  });
```

The problem is that when I close one box all of the boxes close...

Is there a way to modify this so that when you click the image "x" on that specific `DIV` `ID`, only that one closes, and it doesn't close all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('a.close').click(function() { 
     $(this).closest('.Timeline').hide();

     return false; 
});
```

`$(this).closest('.Timeline')` will find the `.Timeline` element that contains the clicked element.  You should replace the `.Timeline` selector as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This code would close the parent `div` of the image that you're clicking on:

```
$("div img").click(function(){
  $(this).closest("div").hide();
});
```

Tied to your `DIV` `ID`s, it would be:

```
$("div[id^='timeline-2010-'] img").click(function(){
  $(this).closest("div").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along this way:

```
  $('a.close').click(function() { 
     $(this).hide(); 
     return false; 
  });
```

The thing here is the `this` that refers to that particular object.